# Merge based on a column which has different names in left- and right- tables

Tags: r, join, merge

I would like to do a vlookup a lookup table in R, hence would like to use merge for that.

The data table looks like this:

[image]

The mapping table looks like this:

[image]

I want to do a vlookup based on the id_type column and type of asset.

My code looks as such:

```
base1 <- (merge(MappingTable, inputData, by = 'Id_type'))
```

When I do so, I get this error:

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: There is no `Id_type` in the second dataset

Comment: `base1 <- (merge(MappingTable, inputData,by.x="Type Of Asset",by.y="Id_type"))`

Comment: Don't post pictures, post real data pls!

Comment: "VLOOKUP" is Excel for "join/merge". You want to join on **one** column which has different names in the left and right tables (`by.x, by.y`), **not on two columns** (which is a pretty rare thing to need to do).

Answer (score 0):

@lakesh u can do with `dplyr` package also with **full_join** :

```
 library(dplyr)
 base1<-full_join(MappingTable,inputData,by=c("Type Of 
           Asset","Id_type"),all=TRUE)%>%arrange(Idenitifier) ##if u want to ##make order by something use **arrange**
```